# react Router, add variable to url before view routing

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, url-routing

I started to build next website using `reactJS` and `nodejs`. The website is required to have minimum 2 languages and it should be possible to share link to website in desired language. I concluded quickly that what i need is to have following url structure

```
domain.com/en-GB
domain.com/en-GB/gallery
domain.com/en-GB/contact
```

front end `Router`:

```
  import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

  ...
  <Router>
    <React.Fragment>
      <Header />
        <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Landing />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/gallery">
              <Gallery />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/about-us">
              <AboutUs />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/contact">
              <Contact />
            </Route>
            <Route>
              <PageNotFound />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </Suspense>
      <Footer />
    </React.Fragment>
  </Router>
  ...
```

front end menu:

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

...
<NavLink to="/about-us">
    {Lang.resolve("HEADER_MENU_ABOUT_US")}
</NavLink>
...
```

pieces of webpack config:

```
...
const extractTextPlugin = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: "css/style.[hash:8].css",
  allChunks: true
});

module.exports = {
  ...
  output: {
    filename: "js/main.[hash:8].js"
  }
  ...
},
...
```

server routing:

```
...
const router = express.Router();

let landing = (req, res, next) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../../index.html")); // html build by webpack
};

router.get("/", landing);
router.get("/:view", landing);
...
```

I was wondering if there is something already baked into `reactJS` to allow this or i need to manually append `language` part of url like: `<Route path={_LANG_ + "/gallery"}>`.

Probably some adjustments are also needed to the server routing and webpack paths otherwise it will be a problem while loading css, js files `domain.com/en-GB/css/style.css`.

Maybe someone already fought this idea and could have some tips.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you gonna handle the translations on each component, but if you have different components (according to the language), then an option would be having different *"basenames"* on your **Router**:

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/calendar">
<Link to="/today"/> // renders <a href="/calendar/today">
<Link to="/tomorrow"/> // renders <a href="/calendar/tomorrow">
...
</BrowserRouter>
```

From the documentation:
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string

Similar question:
[Multiple BrowserRouter Shows Multiple Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52481536/multiple-browserrouter-shows-multiple-components)

Comment: the thing is that having 5 components to render the same thing just because you have 5 languages, its pretty duplicative and bad practice. Language strings are just taken from translation file and injected `{Lang.resolve("TRANSLATION_KEY")}`, so this solution is probably very poor one.

Comment: Now that you explicitly gave us more information, I agree this is a poor one for your approach. I found this article: https://medium.com/prototyped/multi-language-routing-in-react-d7eb7a0688e9. It uses react-intl from FormatJS. Maybe it give you a hint?